# Ajax form view issue, asp.net mvc 3

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to add some ajax to my forms. Here is the main view:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

// here I display each post from Posts collection
@foreach (var post in Model.Posts)
{   
<div>
<div>
    <strong>
        Title: @post.Title
    </strong>
</div>
<div>@post.Text</div>
<div>Posted by: @post.User.UserName</div>
<div>Posted Date: @post.CreatedDate</div>

@{ var membershipUser = Membership.GetUser(); }
@if (membershipUser != null)
{
    var providerUserKey = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey;
    if (providerUserKey != null && post.CreatedBy == (Guid) providerUserKey)
    {
        <div style="display: none; color: red;" id="postEditLoading">Loading..</div>

        <p id="postEdit">

            // EditPost method returns edit view asynchronously

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditPost", new {id = post.PostId, @class = "averageLink"},
                new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "postEdit", LoadingElementId = "postEditLoading", LoadingElementDuration = 3000})

            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeletePost", new {id = post.PostId}, new {@class = "averageLink"})
        </p>
    }
}
```

Everything works, except for this strange thing: the form that is returned by EditPost method appeares right below first post, whether I wanna edit first or last post.

How could I fix this, so the form will appear below the post I want to edit??

Thanks for help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because of the updatetargetid that you used in your ActionLink. The id of updated element is "postEdit" but for each item you'll create a p with the same id. I think you must change the id of p based on each item and also change updatetargetid based on that item.

something like this:

```
@{string UpdatepID = "postEdit" + post.PostId;}
<p id=@UpdatepID>

            // EditPost method returns edit view asynchronously

            @Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "EditPost", new {id = post.PostId, @class = "averageLink"},
                new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = UpdatepID, LoadingElementId = "postEditLoading", LoadingElementDuration = 3000})
```

Comment: I get an error with "UpdateTargetId = @UpdatepID" and "<p id="@UpdatepID">" lines : cannot resolve symbol 'UpdatepID'. Besides I wrapped postEdit with double quotes, cause there is no such member. What did I do wrong?

Comment: yes, I found my mistake) Your code works perfectly fine! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have these 2 tags for each post, don't you?

```
    <div id="postEditLoading">Loading..</div>

    <p id="postEdit">
    </p>
```

In this case you have multiple tags with the same id, what is really a violation of html. And in that case js  takes first tag, which it can reach.

To fix it, you can name your tags based on some post info:

```
    <div id="postEditLoading-@post.PostId">Loading..</div>

    <p id="postEdit-@post.PostId">
    </p>
```

Comment: do I need to change UpdateTargetId value the same way? I tried both - doesn't work: pressing the link - nothing happend